# Run Selenium test case in time interval from a console application C#

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, c#

How do I create a console app - a batch file which will hit my Automation testing application and runs selected test cases?

I have test cases with code coverage and it runs from Visual Studio. Now on top of it, I have to create a console app which will keep some time interval and hit my VS test case and execute it. Any links will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to build your own [CI/CD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CI/CD) system. Although it can be done in a console app I would rather research a system build to schedule builds and testruns.

For the C# eco system have a look at [Azure DevOps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/) as a scheduler for building/testing your applications. Or other free tools: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/ci-cd-tools-comparison-jenkins-gitlab-ci-buildbot-drone-and-concourse

Answer (score 1):

Try [Windows Task Scheduler](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler). I used to have a PowerShell script run tests at midnight, upload the results, and then email me if anything was off. As a long term solution I would use CI/CD, like Niels said.